# How to compare two numpy array according to True and False statements

Tags: python, numpy

```
self.x = np.array( [np.random.uniform( -5, 5 ) for _ in xrange( 100 )] )
v = np.array( [np.random.uniform( -5, 5 ) for _ in xrange( 100 )] )
good = np.random.uniform(0,1,5) < 0.5
good = good.reshape(1,self.x.shape[1])
self.x[good] = v[good]
u = self.x[good]
```

Let's suppose that `good` is `[False  True  True  True  True]`. `u` vector discards the first value which is False, the rest is replaced which is True. but i want it to keep previous value of `self.x`

Comment: Is this your actual code? It gives an error since x is one dimensional.  IndexError: tuple index out of range, at x.shape[1].

Comment: Note that it's usually better to write `self.x = np.random.uniform(-5, 5, size=100)` instead: shorter, easier to read, and faster.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you want `x` and `v` to remain unchanged, but to have a third vector `u` which is `v` wherever `good` is `True`, but `x` elsewhere?  To do this, you can use the function `np.where`.

Here's an example:

```
x = np.arange(1,6)
v = 10*x
good = np.array([False, True, True, True, True])

In [690]: x
Out[690]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [691]: v
Out[691]: array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])

In [692]: good
Out[692]: array([False,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [693]: u = np.where(good, v, x)

In [694]: u
Out[694]: array([ 1, 20, 30, 40, 50])

In [695]: x
Out[695]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [696]: v
Out[696]: array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50])
```

Comment: You're welcome @user2374431, feel free to select my answer with the green checkmark, to show that you are satisfied with the solution.